# ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem on WIN x64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

**Info about my system:**

`ruby -v` -> ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]

`gem -v` -> 1.8.24

---

when i'm running

```
bundle install
```

output:

```
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not find ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26 in any of the sources
```

the firewall is OFF

I downloaded this file: ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem

but when i run:

```
gem install ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem
```

outputs:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby
        --with-ruby-dir
        --without-ruby-dir
        --with-ruby-include
        --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
        --with-ruby-lib
        --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
extconf.rb:16:in `block in <main>': break from proc-closure (LocalJumpError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_sour
ce-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_sour
ce-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:18:in `create_makefile_with_core'
        from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debu
g-base19-0.11.26/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out
```

what's the problem??

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the `--with-ruby-include` options with `ruby-debug-base19`. In your case try:

```
gem install ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby-1.9.3-p125
```

Alternatively look at the [`debugger` gem](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger). It seems to cut a lot of fat off the other debugging gems, plus it actually works and installs easily!

Answer (score 2):

Open your Gemfile

See if there's something like this...

```
gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

Comment it out, and use 'debugger' instead

```
#gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
gem 'debugger'
```